# How to remove the gen folder from svn:ignore

Tags: android, subclipse

I am using Subclipse to connect to a SVN repo where I have check in my Android project. I need Subclipse to pickup my R.java too, (to make the long story short, some team members need the whole thing to generate jni headers).

So my question is how to get subclipse to pick it up? I tried Window->preferences. Also Team -- show properties (it is blank, no svn:ignore property)

The gen folder is in the repository, but empty.

How to do it?

EDIT: Thanks to an answer from Chris, I right-clicked on the package-name inside the gen folder and clicked Team --> Add to version control. I got a warning & when I clicked OK, it did **seem** to add the missing package.

However, inside the repo, the gen directory is still empty. R.java still does not show the little repo icon that other source files have. I committed the gen folder, refreshed the repo, even restarted eclipse. Same thing

If I retry Team --> Add to version control on that package, I get an "already in repo" error. But cannot see it there :-( . Not sure why.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this issue?  I am having a similar issue, i.e. trying to add a directory to the repository which was previously added to svn:ignore.  I add it to version control and commit but it never appears in the repository.  If you ever found a solution to this problem then please post.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

just right-click the gen folder and use Team->Add to Version Control, that should work i think

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the gen folder was already there, but empty, I right clicked on the package name within it and did just as you suggested. It went ahead and after a warning seemed to add it. But inside the repo, gen is still empty. Please see EDIT in the question for details.